# Compressing strings before putting them in redis - does it make sense?

Tags: compression, redis

A bit more detail: we're already trying to take the most advantage of zipmaps, ziplists, etc, and I'm wondering whether these representations are already compressed, or are just serialized hashes and lists; does compression significantly reduce memory usage?

Also, does compression overhead at the app server layer get offset by lower network usage? [StackOverflow's experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how) suggests it does, any other opinions?

In brief, does it make sense - for both short and longer strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis and clients are typically IO bound and the IO costs are typically at least 2 orders of magnitude in respect to the rest of the request/reply sequence.  Smaller payloads will give you higher throughput and lower latencies.

I do not believe there are any hard and fast rules beyond: `cost of compression << IO gains`.  You should bench it and find the sweat spot in setting the lower bound, but the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of your network is not a bad starting point for the lower bound.

Comment: I've found [this benchmark](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/04/compressing-large-data-sets-in-redis-with-gzip-ruby-test-case/) very useful and [these additional thoughts](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/46926679137/compressing-large-data-sets-in-redis-with-gzip) as well.

Answer (score 16):

Redis does not compress your values, and if you should compress them yourself depends a lot on the size of the strings you are going to store. For big strings, hundreds of K's and more it's probably worth the extra CPU cycles on the client side, just like it is when you serve web pages, but for shorter strings it's likely a waste of time. Short strings generally don't compress much, so the gain would be too small.

Comment: So, for something that is about 10K, you say don't compress - am I right? What about a specific case, where you have a lot of content that is consistently about 2 to 5K of JSON, low-level gzipping should slash the memory footprint of those by a factor of 2 at least, especially if those end up represented as zipmaps? Or am I wrong

Comment: If you can decrease the size of your strings by a factor of two, then by all means, you should compress them. What I'm saying is that it's not at all sure that you will get enough compression on small strings. Depending on the contents of the strings, 2-5K may be too low. XML compresses very nicely because of repeated tag names, but image data in JPEG, GIF or PNG doesn't compress at all since it's already compressed, other kinds of data has other properties. Test loading uncompressed data and look at the memory usage (`redis-cli info | grep used_memory`) and then with compressed data.

Answer (score 9):

There's a practical way to get good compression, even for very small strings (50 bytes!) -

If your values are somewhat similar to each other - for example, they're JSON representations of a few related classes of objects - you can precompute a compressor/decompressor dictionary based on some example text.

It sounds complicated, but it's simple in practice - and simpler still with the right wrapper code to handle it.

Here's a Python implementation:

https://github.com/internetarchive/openlibrary/blob/master/openlibrary/utils/compress.py

and here's a wrapper for compressing a specific class of strings: (short JSON records)

https://github.com/internetarchive/openlibrary/blob/master/openlibrary/utils/olcompress.py

One catch: to do this efficiently, your compression library must support 'cloning' the internal state.  (The Python library does)  You can implement something similar by prepending the example text when compressing, but this means paying an extra computation cost.

Thanks to solrize for this awesome trick.